Where can I ask questions related to BitcoinGold?
I got here since my question about BitcoinGold was closed. Search brought me to a similar topic:
Where can I ask questions related to other cryptocurrencies?
But where to ask a question about BitcoinGold?

The Bitcoin Gold community appears to be organizing themselves via bitcoingold.org. The page links in the "Our Community" section to:

Forum
Discord
r/BitcoinGoldHQ

